# Permission Denied in Kali Linux

Tags: permissions, apt, kali-linux

I tried to upgrade my tools but it wont let me do it, and it drop me this

```
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
```

Comment: If you're new to Linux, please consult the google search and try to figure out if the problem is this much trivial from next time

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that Kali Linux is not intended for Linux beginners (your question seems to indicate that you are; I apologize if I misinterpret this); you may want to try another distribution such as Ubuntu or Linux Mint unless you are absolutely sure that you need Kali Linux ...

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`.

If you didn't add any sudoer, then swith to root by - `su`

The default password  is **toor** I think. Now your update should run fine

Answer (score 0):

you have to simply switch to root directory

```
sudo -s
```

And check it

```
fdisk -l
```

command working if yes then go ahead

After that write the command line which is used for persistency.

```
mkdir -p /mnt/my_usb
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/my_usb
```

sdb2 is the directory where Linux is present.

If you can't find the entry in /etc/fstab, then try once again and remove the '-p' from command:

```
mkdir /mnt/my_usb
mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt/my_usb
```

Add a configuration file to enable persistence:

`echo "/ union" > /mnt/my_usb/persistence.conf`

Unmount the partition and reboot:

`umount /dev/sdb2 && reboot`